# What would cause extra records to be inserted during a INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

The following trigger that joins **Inserted** table on itself creates multiple unwanted records:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trFooInsert] on [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Inserted a
                LEFT JOIN Inserted b ON b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
                WHERE b.Flag IS NULL AND a.Flag = 0
                ) -- exists
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Foo(ID, Etc, Flag)              
        SELECT a.ID, a.Etc, 1 FROM Inserted a
            LEFT JOIN Inserted b ON b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
            WHERE b.Flag IS NULL AND a.Flag = 0
    END -- insert
END -- trigger
```

Where as this trigger that joins **Inserted** on **Foo** (the table that the trigger is linked to) creates one record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trFooInsert] on [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Inserted a
                LEFT JOIN Foo b ON b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
                WHERE b.Flag IS NULL AND a.Flag = 0
                ) -- exists
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Foo(ID, Etc, Flag)              
        SELECT a.ID, a.Etc, 1 FROM Inserted a
            LEFT JOIN Foo b ON b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
            WHERE b.Flag IS NULL AND a.Flag = 0
    END -- insert
END -- trigger
```

The second trigger does exactly what I want, but I'm trying why the first trigger creates so many records. I would've expected **Inserted** and **Foo** to be identical when the trigger fires. Is there any kind of special property/behaviour that the Inserted table exhibits when joining on itself.

Apologies if there's not enough info, I've tried to reduce to the basic differences between the two triggers.

**Update #1**

I'm trying to backfill the table with records where the user account has transactions, but doesn't have the flag set.

**Update #2**

The inserts are carried out by a C# app. The data source is flat file where each line represents a single row in the table. I don't know if the app uses connection pooling or if this matters. The bulk inserts are done once a month. The C# app usually imports 8373 rows. The 1st trigger inserts 50 additional row, there's only one row that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the `IF EXISTS` part in your trigger code. You have the exact same code in the second part so if there are 0 rows produced, you'll be inserting 0 rows anyway:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trFooInsert] on [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Foo(ID, Etc, Flag)              
    SELECT a.ID, a.Etc, 1 FROM Inserted a
        LEFT JOIN Foo b ON b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
        WHERE b.Flag IS NULL AND a.Flag = 0
END ; -- trigger
```

which can also be written as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trFooInsert] on [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Foo(ID, Etc, Flag)              
    SELECT a.ID, a.Etc, 1 
        FROM Inserted a
        WHERE a.Flag = 0
          AND NOT EXISTS
              ( SELECT *
                FROM Foo b 
                WHERE b.Flag = 1 AND a.ID = b.ID
              )
END ; -- trigger
```

So, you want any insert on the table with `Flag=0` to also trigger another insert, with same data but `Flag=1` (unless there is already a row in `Foo` with that `ID` and `Flag=1`.

---

Second, and what the actual problem is about, `Inserted` is a special table with all the (just) "inserted" rows, not the full table you inserted into. It obviously has less (than or equal) rows as `Foo` after the insert. So a join to it will not give same results as a join to `Foo`.

The trigger that produces the multiple unwanted rows had `Inserted b` instead of `Foo b` so it does this:

For any insert on the table with `Flag=0` it also triggered another insert, with same data but `Flag=1` (unless this same insert had such a row inserted).

You can read more about the special **`Inserted`** and **`Deleted`** tables at the MSDN:
[How to use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: This article has some performance tests: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/). But performance is highly affected by what indexes you have, the sizes of the tables and many other factors which you only can test.

Comment: I also talk about [NOT EXISTS as the preferred approach here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: I would use SET NOCOUNT ON in any trigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage. Also, to avoid a zero row trigger, I'd have IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN as the first line